# Nitrogen Flow Problem

Tags: fluid-mechanics

If I have a tank of nitrogen gas at 2000 psi (13.79 MPa) and a pipe of 10 mm cross sectional area and 1 meter long how long would it take to fill another, initially empty tank, to 5 L at 1000 psi (6.89 MPa)? Assume to 2000 psi (13.79 MPa) never drops and the initial source is unlimited

I have tried a couple of things so far:

Renouard Equation: p2i−p2f=46,742 $ρLq^{1.82}D^{−4.82}$⟹4391.11 L/s unreasonable

Panhandle Equation: -12166 L/s unreasonable

Weymouth Equation: 1066 L/s better but still an awful lot

Tried using experimental data: with this I know at the initial condition of 2000 psi (13.79 MPa) I have 228 ft<sup>3</sup> (6.456 m<sup>3</sup>) and in 5 seconds the pressure drops to 1750 psi (12.066 MPa) but I no longer know how much gas is left.

Any help is much appreciated on this, thanks.

Comment: tuning impossible scenarios like unlimited sources with experimental data... Well ignoring that: consider treating it as an ideal gas (or using Nitrogen gas tables) and make some temperature assumptions.

Comment: Continuing on from Abel: Is the actual tank size 228 $ft^3$? what kind of pipe are you using (there are not many types that can sustain 2000 psi).

Comment: According to my tank it holds 228ft^3 of nitrogen gas at 2000psi. I believe the pipe is made of stainless steel. I don't really understand how treating this as an ideal gas would help because ultimately I need to find the volume or mass flow rate. Would something like the isentropic flow equation be helpful? I also read that perhaps this could be solved considering that this is a 'mass flow choking' problem?

Comment: So I just tried this problem using NASA's mass flow choking calculator and I ended up getting 2444L/s at 2000psi and 1264L/s at 1000psi ( I did both because I am not sure what pressure is correct). This means it would take roughly 0.0025 seconds to fill the 5L tank at either pressure. Seems like another unreasonable value to me. Thoughts? https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/mflchk.html

Comment: so ive done more research into this problem and I think it is safe to say that this is in fact adiabatic flow and I have used an isentropic flow equation but I am still getting erroneous results. Does anyone have some concrete advice?